# If my website layout is set up for a resolution of 800x600, can I zoom in my website to fit the user's resolution if it is a higher resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I worded my question wrong before, my intention wasn't to change the resolution of the user's browser settings. I'm mainly wanting to layout my page for the smallest common resolution size and have it zoom in to fit the resolution if the user's resolution has a higher setting. Like if the user's resolution is 800x600, my website will look just like I designed it, but if the user's resolution is 1280x800, my website will zoom in to fit that resolution without changing the layout of my website, which would make the font and size of everything bigger while keeping the same look and layout of the website. If there is a way, how can I? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A browser changing the resolution of my monitor? I certainly hope not!

Comment: If you figure out how to change someone's screen resolution you win.

Comment: You have it backwards. YOU need to change, not the client. Make your site responsive.

Comment: Changing a user's resolution wouldn't annoy them at all...

Comment: If something like that existed, why would people struggle with different resolutions. It would also be a major problem for users if websites could just randomly change the resolution (which is'nt so much the browser, but the screen).

Comment: "I know many people have been struggling with getting their websites to fit to all resolution sizes " Those are the ones that do not understand fluid/responsive layouts. :)

Comment: These seems like a horrible idea. It would make your site less Accessible to those with any kind of visual impairment - and for those of us who don't have any impairment I'm awfully unlikely to come back to a site that changes my settings. Sounds a lot like the sites that used to resize the browser window to make their site look better.

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying, I guess another way to say it is, like with a software program or a video that runs full screen. The resolution fits to the users resolution without changing the look and outline of the software or video. Is there a way to do the same on a website?

Comment: You should re-ask your question, maybe...

Answer (score 3):

No there is not. This would be very annoying for the client. You have to have to change your site to fit the users resolution. As the comments suggest, make it responsive. If you search for responsive web design you'll find a lot of articles on ways to do it. We are sometimes limited in javascript because some things would be a security issue (this one would be more of an annoyance).

> Just think about it - while browsing the web - if every website you
>   visited changed your monitor's resolution!

So to sum up, the reason that so many make their site fit the users resolution is because you can't change the user's resolution.

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying, I guess another way to say it is, like with a software program or a video that runs full screen. The resolution fits to the users resolution without changing the look and outline of the software or video. Is there a way to do the same on a website?

Comment: Yes there is (within the browser window). This is what we call responsive design. It is done in a lot of ways and which way you should go depends on what exactly you want to achieve. I would look into javascript and detecting the user's window width/Height :) Atleast I think that's your scenario. Simply changing your website depending on the size of your user's viewport (browser window). I would give it a try and ask a question here ON Stack overflow if you get stuck.

Comment: Yes that is pretty much what I'm asking. I can see the annoyance of changing the users resolution. That wasn't really what I had in mind. I'm mostly trying to find a way for my website to zoom in or out to the users resolution like a full screen video. If the user's resolution is 800x600, it'll look this way and if the user's resolution is 1280x800 it'll still look the same way. If the user has a visual impairment, then they would have to zoom in but would have to scroll to see the whole page.

Comment: I'm glad you got your question answered. At the end of the day I believe we all would like to change the users resolution sometimes, but when you think about the consequences - you don't want it to be possible anyway. I wish you good luck on your responsive design adventure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, and you shouldn't.

You'll have to make your web site accommodate the user's current browser window size as best you can. You have no control over the browser window size or screen resolution and even if you did, it would be unprofessional and impolite to change these things without such a change being understood by and initiated by the user.

The browser is not the computer. It is just one application among many. You don't know what the user is doing with his screen--what if he is playing a video in one corner and wants his browser window exactly where it is?

What if he is visually impaired and has his browser zoomed in like crazy? I know someone who wears thick glasses, uses the on-screen screen zoom accessibility box, and still leans in to about 6 inches from the screen to be able to see anything. You would *not* be doing him a favor to change *anything* about how his browser and screen are laid out.

Any website that somehow changed how my browser to fit the screen, altered my browser's resolution, or changed my monitor's resolution would:

1. Be instantly added to my "forever hate list" and never visited again.
2. Be worth telling all my technical friends about it to get them to laugh
3. Be submitted to thedailywtf.com for future folks to marvel at
4. Be in my next blog post about software not being arrogantly evil and not acting like it owns the user's computer, a subject I have never blogged about before but would be utterly compelled to do so in this case
5. Receive a polite but pointed email that such meddling with my computer without permission is unprofessional and rude, and furthermore that the offending decision-maker who approved it should be soundly whipped.

There *are* video playing plugins that can maximize to full screen **at user request and user request only**. Doing such a thing requires a java applet.

Comment: This is essentially a very long comment - nothing here answers the question.

Comment: I beg to differ. "Don't do that" is a perfectly valid answer to a technical question. I will update my question to highlight this.

Comment: The new first paragraph is much more answer-esque :)

Comment: I reworded my question and description, I see the confusion of what I was asking and why you answered it the way you did. Can you please review the question one more time, I asked it before without putting much thought into the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated in the previous answers changing the screen resolution may be a bad idea (if not simply impossible), but you can change the scale of the contents so it exactly fits your window.

I wrote the piece of code below for a web application I designed for devices with exactly a 1280x800 resolution. In the end I decided to also occasionally use it on a 1080p screen, so some scaling was required to get it to fit perfectly. This is what my code below does.

I am using the fullscreen API (this wrapper: http://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/) to make the browser go full screen via a button and this same button triggers the auto scaling at the same time. You can find a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QT5Nr/5/

Beware this piece of code currently requires [jQuery 1.8.3](http://jquery.com/) and [screenfull.js](http://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js/), but can easily be changed to work without them. I left my comment on top intact to explain why I override the jQuery offset function. You can also test why I did that by commenting that piece of code out in the jsFiddle, then resizing the frame.

```
/*****************************************************************************************************************************************\
|**                                                     Scale elements to fit page                                                      **|
|*****************************************************************************************************************************************|
|** Because we created a static size layout for our target device other devices will not have a 100% sized layout. To fix this we       **|
|** change the scale of the body element so that it's contents fit exactly within the available window.                                 **|
|** In addition we have to override jQuery.fn.offset in order to fix problems where the offset returned by this function is exact to    **|
|** the current location of the element (with it's scale), while it has to be the exact location of the unscaled element.               **|
\*****************************************************************************************************************************************/
function EnableAutoScale() {
    function AdjustScale() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();

        var viewportWidth = $('#viewport').width();
        var viewportHeight = $('#viewport').height();

        var horizontalScale = windowWidth / viewportWidth;
        var verticalScale = windowHeight / viewportHeight;

        $(document.body).css('transform-origin', '0 0');
        $(document.body).css('transform', 'scale(' + horizontalScale + ', ' + verticalScale + ')');
        document.body.HorizontalScale = horizontalScale;
        document.body.VerticalScale = verticalScale;
    }

    $(AdjustScale);
    $(window).resize(AdjustScale);

    // Override offset so it continues working with the scale set above
    jQuery.fn.originalOffset = jQuery.fn.offset;
    jQuery.fn.offset = function () {
        var offset = jQuery.fn.originalOffset.apply(this, arguments);

        offset.left = offset.left / document.body.HorizontalScale;
        offset.top = offset.top / document.body.VerticalScale;

        return offset;
    };
}
$(function () {
    $('#fullscreen').click(function () {
        $('#fullscreen').hide();

        EnableAutoScale();

        if (screenfull.enabled)
            screenfull.toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: finally, someone that understood my question lol thanks a lot, that makes sense :)